# Multiple designs in one Photoshop mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, mockup

I'm trying to use this mockup to showcase 3 different designs on 3 boxes. I found this mockup that has 3 boxes and within the PS file you can see it's broken up into Left box, Right box, Top box. But when I go into the Left box 'front side' smart object to add my design, it does it across all front panels. How can I edit just the panels for each box?

I'm sorry for the stupid question, it's just really bugging me!

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a smart object is duplicated, it is linked to the original one.
If you want to create a new smart object based on another one without this link, you need to do right click on the layer in the layer panel and choose `New smart object via copy`.

In your example you already have a smart object linked, so you need to copy it with `new smart object via copy` and delete (or disable) the one linked. That way it will remain the same but no longer linked to the others.

Comment: Ah amazing!! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much! As you can tell I'm a bit of a Smart Object novice. Thanks again :)

Comment: You're English is excellent. `:)` No need to worry about that.